# Javascript array arrange parent and child as array?

Tags: javascript

how can I create a Parent with Nested child as array format? The child will depend to the parent id and they will be groups as an array under "squads" key?

Sample Input:

```
        let sample = [
          { tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squad_id: 1, squad_name: "Squad A" },
          { tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squad_id: 2, squad_name: "Squad B" },
          { tribe_id: 2, tribe_name: "Tribe B", squad_id: 3, squad_name: "Squad C" }
        ];
        console.log(sample);
```

Desired Output:

```
        let desiredFormat = [
          {
            tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squads: [
              {squad_id: 1, squad_name: "Squad A"},
              {squad_id: 2, squad_name: "Squad B"}
            ]
          },
          { 
            tribe_id: 2, tribe_name: "Tribe B", squads: [
              {squad_id: 3, squad_name: "Squad C"}
            ]
          }
        ];
        console.log(desiredFormat);
```

What I tried so far:

```
let origArray = sample;
let tempArray = [];
let finalArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++) {
    tempArray.push({ tribe_id: origArray[i].tribe_id, tribe_name: origArray[i].tribe_name, squads: [ origArray[i].squad_id] });
}

for (let i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {

    let uniqueTribeId = tempArray[i].tribe_id;

    for (let z = 0; z < origArray.length; z++) {
        if (uniqueTribeId == origArray[z].tribe_id) {
            finalArr.push( { tribe_id: uniqueTribeId, squads: [] });
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: [There’s work to be done, whether it is homework or an assigned task , the person to whom it was assigned is expected to complete it. Even if it seems the task is too hard or there isn’t a clear starting point, an effort should be made.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: It is not completely clear for me how the output relates to the input.

Comment: I won't downvote it, but as @Liam mentioned, this looks awfully like some assigned homework, and it does not seem like you actually tried doing it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I'm in a tight deadline with lack of sleep and did not construct the question properly. Editing it now.

Comment: hi @Liam sorry. I updated now my question properly, I was in a rush a while ago.

Comment: So what exactly is `tempArray` and `origArray`? It'd be much easier if you built a proper [mcve]. Also what is the question? Or are you just wanting someone to simply debug this for you? I'm not sure half heartily dumping a lump of barely thought though code really helps this question

Comment: @Liam the "sample = origArray" and "desiredFormat = tempArray". I'm looping the original array to create a unique array of tribe_ids and then I'm looping again the original array to put the squad child objects if their tribe_id match.

Comment: @marknt15 please edit the question, don't add details in comments

Comment: @Liam I solved it already yay! I was just tired and sleepy last time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution:

```
let final = [];
let sample = [
  { tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squad_id: 1, squad_name: "Squad A" },
  { tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squad_id: 2, squad_name: "Squad B" },
  { tribe_id: 2, tribe_name: "Tribe B", squad_id: 3, squad_name: "Squad C" }
];
console.log(sample);

const uniqueTribes = sample.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.tribe_id === current.tribe_id);
  if (!x) {
    // return acc.concat([current]);
    return acc.concat([{ "tribe_id": current.tribe_id, "tribe_name": current.tribe_name, "squads": [] }]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
// console.log(uniqueTribes);

for (let i = 0; i < uniqueTribes.length; i++) {

  let uniqueTribeName = uniqueTribes[i].tribe_name;
  let uniqueTribeId = uniqueTribes[i].tribe_id;

  for (let x = 0; x < sample.length; x++) {
    let squadName = sample[x].squad_name;
    let squadId = sample[x].squad_id;

    if (uniqueTribeId == sample[x].tribe_id) {
      // uniqueTribes[i].squads.push({ squad_id: sample[x].squad_id, squad_name: sample[x].squad_name });
      uniqueTribes[i].squads.push({ squad_id: squadId, squad_name: squadName });

    }
  }
  // let uniqueTribeId = sample[i].squad_name;
}
console.log(uniqueTribes);



let tribe = [];

// console.log(tribe);

let desiredFormat = [
  {
    tribe_id: 1, tribe_name: "Tribe A", squads: [
      {squad_id: 1, squad_name: "Squad A"},
      {squad_id: 2, squad_name: "Squad B"}
    ]
  },
  { 
    tribe_id: 2, tribe_name: "Tribe B", squads: [
      {squad_id: 3, squad_name: "Squad C"}
    ]
  }
];
```